# Problems with WiFi adapter TL-WN822N on Debian jessie

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, wifi-driver

After some time of using WiFi I get the following: wifi is still connected, but there is no internet access. How can I fix it? Any other information is needed?

> dmesg

```
[ 3104.614783] wlan0: deauthenticating from MAC by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3104.615294] rtl8192c_common:rtl92c_fill_h2c_cmd(): return H2C cmd because of Fw download fail!!!
[ 3104.627479] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 3104.641365] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 3104.641369] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 3104.641371] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 3104.641374] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3104.641376] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3104.641378] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3104.641380] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3104.641383] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 3104.641385] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 3104.641387] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3104.641389] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[ 3105.354898] wlan0: authenticate with MAC
[ 3105.354906] wlan0: capabilities/regulatory prevented using AP HT/VHT configuration, downgraded
[ 3105.378405] wlan0: send auth to MAC (try 1/3)
[ 3105.406062] wlan0: authenticated
[ 3105.410305] wlan0: associate with MAC (try 1/3)
[ 3105.431422] wlan0: RX AssocResp from MAC (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3105.431444] rtl8192c_common:rtl92c_fill_h2c_cmd(): return H2C cmd because of Fw download fail!!!
[ 3105.431460] rtl8192cu:rtl92cu_set_hw_reg():<0-0> switch case not processed
[ 3105.431463] rtl8192c_common:rtl92c_fill_h2c_cmd(): return H2C cmd because of Fw download fail!!!
[ 3105.432390] rtl8192c_common:rtl92c_fill_h2c_cmd(): return H2C cmd because of Fw download fail!!!
[ 3105.432396] rtl8192c_common:rtl92c_fill_h2c_cmd(): return H2C cmd because of Fw download fail!!!
[ 3105.432419] wlan0: associated
[ 3105.432428] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
return H2C cmd because of Fw download fail!!!
```

is harmless, as the author of the driver states [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/27.0%20dBm):

> Those Fw download messages can and should be ignored. You will get more information by loading the module with the "debug=3" option; however, that will generate a lot of info and may fill up your storage.

Your real problem is here,

```
 capabilities/regulatory prevented using AP HT/VHT configuration, downgraded
```

This can be cured by creating a file `/etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf` with the following text,

```
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=US
```

(or whatever **your** regulatory domain is), then rebooting.

But most important, make sure you have the latest kernel available, and the latest driver. If for any reason you cannot update the kernel to a reasonably new version, then install the relevant driver from the Linux Kernel backport repo, [here](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/). As they state,

> We provide drivers released on newer kernels backported for usage on older kernels